# How to print 2 double arrays, the second one should be cumulative totals of the elements of the first array , in 1 loop?

Tags: c

In the book he said it's possible with either nested loop, or 1 loop

The user should provide the 8 double numbers for the program to set the cumulative totals in the second array.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ASIZE 8

int main()

{
    int index = 0, x, index2;
    double cal;
    double array1[ASIZE], array2[ASIZE];

    printf("Please enter 8 numbers:\n");
    for (index = 0; index < ASIZE; index++)//adding the numbers to the first array 
    {
        scanf("%lf", &array1[index]);
    }

    for (x = 0,index2 = 0,index = 0; x < ASIZE; x++, index2++)//adding the second array the elements
    {
        cal += array1[index++];
        array2[index2] = cal;
    }

    printf("the first array numbers are:\n");//printing the first array numbers 
    for (index = 0; index < ASIZE; index++)
    {
        printf("%.1lf ", array1[index]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("the second array numbers are:\n");//printing the second array
    for (index2 = 0; index2 < ASIZE; index2++)
    {
        printf("%.1lf ", array2[index2]);
    }



}
```

I'm a beginner in C, and its important for me to know how to get better.

Comment: I wanted to know how is it possible to do it in 1 loop...and hoe bad is this code(for a beginner)?@Kirilenko

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your question is to use either nested loop, or 1 loop.You can do this in one loop, as and when u get the input

```
for (index = 0; index < ASIZE; index++)//adding the numbers to the first array 
    {
        scanf("%lf", &array1[index]);
        cal += array1[index];
        array2[index] = cal;
    }
```

Infact, you can print both the arrays in the same `for` loop.

Comment: thank you! Could you please also tell me if this code looks ok for a newbie?

Comment: These are the basics. and a newbie would know it.

Comment: Thank you for the suppor...there are probably allot of ways to solve it. Just wanted to know if mine looks ok.@Sibrajas